# WebRTC: How can I setup a signling-server and webserver together?

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to transfer files between two devices (browsers) using WebRTC. I followed this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster) to setup the `signalmaster` signaling-server, and it works fine. So, I put a simple `index.html` page in the same folder. But when I goto `http://localhost:8888`, it doesn't show the page. I then figure out that the Signaling server is not a webserver. So, I setup a webserver using `Web server for chrome`.

At this point I am confused about:

1. the need for signaling-server while having a webserver !! and
2. how I am going to use the signaling server if I am unable to load the webpage !!

in simple, why do I need the signaling-server for if I am already not using it ?! Also, how can I setup a signling-server and webserver together so that my page could load!

Answer (score 1):

This gives a good overview of the role a signaling server plays with WebRTC:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use your current Webpage in combination with nodejs, php and nginx. 
Nodejs and the signaling server are running in the background on port 8888 and with a reverse proxy you can call the webpage without a port in the url.

```
server {
   listen 80 default;

   server_name http://192.168.229.128;


   root /var/www/html;

   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

   location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }


   location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}



   location ~* \.io {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

  proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
  proxy_redirect off;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
   }



}
```

In this case, socket.io is used, but you can remove it, if you want.